# Going past the Chrome security warning

Tags: webdriver

I'm trying to test a page without a security certificate, which Chrome flags up. This blocks my tests. (I have to manually click "Proceed anyway". Is there a way to disable this warning?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning says Chrome does not trust the certificate's issuer.  If you have the certificate of the CA that signed camvine.codeblah.com's certificate, you can import it into Chrome's trusted authority list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what test tool you are using, but can't you just add a click to dismiss this dialog into your script?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet, but I will have to in the future so I've done some research and found this link:  http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=142059

I create new profiles when using firefox, but this doesn't work in all browsers.

To answer the question of whether you can just click on the accept button, the answer is no.  It is not recognized by selenium.  Good luck.